# How service stack handles an object internally?

Tags: c#, servicestack

I am very new to service stack.
Just create a very sample demo rightnow.

I have passed the Object of class when posting the data.
My question is How service stack handles the Object when Posting the request.i.e. JSON/XML etc.

```
   JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient("http://localhost/RestIntro");

        Customer c = new Customer();
        c.Name = "Amit patel";
        c.Age = 30;
        c.Email = "aa";

        var res = client.Post<Customer>("/customers", c);
```

How does this c (Object of Customer) handles when transferring the data?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the [this is the JsonService](https://code.google.com/p/servicestack/source/browse/trunk/Common/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceStack.Client/JsonServiceClient.cs?r=1242&spec=svn1374)

As you can see, the service just [serialises](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Serialization) the customer object, using the [BclJsonDataContractSerializer](https://code.google.com/p/servicestack/source/browse/trunk/Common/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceStack.Client/BclJsonDataContractSerializer.cs?r=1242&spec=svn1374), which uses a [datacontractjsonserializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx), and posts it a json.

Comment: I also thinks so, But do not have strong point to say this as it also support XML,CSV etc. WHat should be the default one as in GENERIC C# client we get JSONSerilaize and XMLSerilaize classes.